# How to Set initial state Redux array of object (list of images info)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, immutable.js

I want to set initial state for array of Images info I want to upload to a server.
I am using [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker)

to select images I want to upload and immutable.js.

my current addImages initial state

```
var InitialState = Record({
    addImages:[],
})
```

Example Image array

```
[
{
  filePath: ../image1.jpg
  description: image 1
},
{
  filePath: ../image2.jpg
  description: image 2
},
.......
]
```

The question is how I list all initial state of image properties since it depends on how many images selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can push all the images in array and assign that array in array of initial state and whenever the images are selected you can dispatch a function that will call reducer to change that initial state array into array of selected images like this:

```
export default function (state:State = initialState, action:Action): State {
  switch(action.type){
   case SELECT_IMAGES:
     return Object.assign({}, state, {
        addImages: action.payload.selectedImages
    });
```

and this change will be reflected in `newProps` which you can catch in `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` in your component.

Comment: This works, but What I need, how to list the properties on initial state (filepath and description) is it possible?

Comment: you can do one thing , make an oject like so: let obj={ filePath: ' ',
  description: ' ' } and then run a loop till the length of array of all images and on every iteration do this: obj['filePath'] = `yourPathAtThatIteraion`; 
                               obj['description']= `yourDescriptionAtThatIteration`; 
addImages.push(obj);